# Showing multiple language support for the android app

Tags: android

I don't have any specific values folder in my android project directory e.g. i have only one values folder and not something like values-fr or values-hi. But while submitting the app to the store, it showed that the app supports 49 languages. Is there a different setting due to which this is happening ?

Comment: Can you post screen shot ?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/support-multiple-languages-in-android-apps/1640 check this link.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something similar in my own app simply because I integrated Google Play Services (for Maps). Apparently this automatically includes a whole set resource files for different languages.

Nothing to really worry about.